# Python, loop through text, search for block

Tags: python, loops, text

I am writing a piece of python code to replace old php code for searching files with various show commands from network equipment. I write the appropiate values in a csv file to generate a cmdb like sheet.
I am now trying to go through a file search for a specific text block and write that to a different temporary file. Here is a piece of the code:

```
for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(cmdbDir):
for d in dirs:
    dir = os.path.join(root, d)
    # Loop through all subdirectories
    with os.scandir(dir) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.name.endswith(".txt") and entry.is_file():
                if dir.endswith('juniper'):
                    manufacturer = 'Juniper'
                    flag = False
                    flag2 = False
                    with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
                        for line in f:
                            # Write a temp file per Juniper Node
                            nodes = ['node0','node1']
                            for node in nodes:
                                tmpfile = (f'{tmpDir}\\{hostname}-{node}.txt')
                                temp_file = open(tmpfile, 'a')
                                if line.startswith(f'set groups {node}'):
                                    temp_file.write(line)

                                # Search for section show chassis hardware
                                if line.startswith('show chassis hardware'):
                                    flag = True
                                elif line.startswith('{primary:node0}'):
                                    flag = False
                                elif flag:
                                    if line.startswith(node):
                                        flag2 = True
                                    elif line.startswith('\n') or len(line) == 0:
                                        flag2 = False
                                    elif flag2:
                                        print(line)
                                        temp_file.write(line)
                                temp_file.close()
```

So it loops through a direectory, and looks in all subdirectories for a file with a .txt extension. With this particular Juniper device, I would like to grep the data for node0, and node1 and put them in seperate files. When I run this code for only 1 node (so I only pass node0 or node1 as argument) it works fine, so the code to grep the text seems ok. When I try the run the code for node0 and node1 something goes wrong with setting the flags I think, then I see the output for bot nodes in both text files.

Here is a piece of the original file I am looping through:

```
show chassis hardware
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                CV3016AF1127      SRX300
Routing Engine   REV 0x08 650-065039   CV3016AF1127      RE-SRX300
FPC 0                                                    FPC
  PIC 0                                                  6xGE,2xGE SFP Base PIC
Power Supply 0

node1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                CV3016AF1125      SRX300
Routing Engine   REV 0x08 650-065039   CV3016AF1125      RE-SRX300
FPC 0                                                    FPC
  PIC 0                                                  6xGE,2xGE SFP Base PIC
Power Supply 0

{primary:node0}
```

So it first looks for text between "show chassis hardware" and {primary:node0} and then looks for thext between "node0" and an empty line, and about the same for node1

The is the result when running this code with only node0:

```
set groups node0 system host-name xxx
set groups node0 interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet address x.x.x.x/26
set groups node0 interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet address x.x.x.x/26 master-only
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                CV3016AF1127      SRX300
Routing Engine   REV 0x08 650-065039   CV3016AF1127      RE-SRX300
FPC 0                                                    FPC
  PIC 0                                                  6xGE,2xGE SFP Base PIC
Power Supply 0
```

And when I run it with node0, node1:

```
set groups node1 system host-name xxx
set groups node1 interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet address x.x.x.x/26
set groups node1 interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet address x.x.x.x/26 master-only
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                CV3016AF1127      SRX300
Routing Engine   REV 0x08 650-065039   CV3016AF1127      RE-SRX300
FPC 0                                                    FPC
  PIC 0                                                  6xGE,2xGE SFP Base PIC
Power Supply 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                CV3016AF1125      SRX300
Routing Engine   REV 0x08 650-065039   CV3016AF1125      RE-SRX300
FPC 0                                                    FPC
  PIC 0                                                  6xGE,2xGE SFP Base PIC
Power Supply 0
```

I am tring to understand where it goes wrong, I think there is something going wrong in the loop, that a certain var is not being unset or stays "active"

I also tried to put the piece of code in a function, but that gave the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "flag2" must be kept separate for the nodes. Use a dictionary (with node name as key) or a list with two entries for it.

Comment: Hi, any code example how I could use this? Or a reference what I could use? Im pretty new in programming/python, so its pretty challenging where to use what function.

Answer (score 0):

`flag2` must be set for each node separately. To do this, move line `nodes = ['node0','node1']` upwards above initial `flag2 = False`. Then replace the latter line by `flag2 = dict.fromkeys(nodes, False)` and each later use of `flag2` by `flag2[node]`.

Then relevant part of the code looks like (not tested):

```
        if dir.endswith('juniper'):
            manufacturer = 'Juniper'
            nodes = ['node0','node1']
            flag = False
            flag2 = dict.fromkeys(nodes, False)
            with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    # Write a temp file per Juniper Node
                    for node in nodes:
                        tmpfile = (f'{tmpDir}\\{hostname}-{node}.txt')
                        temp_file = open(tmpfile, 'a')
                        if line.startswith(f'set groups {node}'):
                            temp_file.write(line)

                        # Search for section show chassis hardware
                        if line.startswith('show chassis hardware'):
                            flag = True
                        elif line.startswith('{primary:node0}'):
                            flag = False
                        elif flag:
                            if line.startswith(node):
                                flag2[node] = True
                            elif line.startswith('\n') or len(line) == 0:
                                flag2[node] = False
                            elif flag2[node]:
                                print(line)
                                temp_file.write(line)
                        temp_file.close()
```